# How to refresh automatically ListView in my app?

Tags: android, listview, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm building an activity that can download some data from a BLE device. Now I want in real time this value in a ListView of my activity.
But I'm not able to do this. This is my code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_ble);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnListListener());
        adapter = new SensorDataAdapter(classe, R.layout.sensordata_row, new LinkedList<SensorData>());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        refreshListViewByPosition(null);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void refreshListViewByPosition(Integer pos) {
        String tipoCaratteristica=null;
        if(pos!=null && pos ==0)
            tipoCaratteristica = CHARACTERISTIC_FORZA_STRING;
        else if(pos!=null && pos ==1)
            tipoCaratteristica = CHARACTERISTIC_TEMPERATURA_STRING;
        listaDati = db.fetchSensorData(tipoCaratteristica);
        if(listaDati== null || listaDati.size() == 0){
            listaDati = new LinkedList<SensorData>();
            SensorData s = new SensorData("NESSUN ELEMENTO MEMORIZZATO");
            listaDati.add(s);
        }
        adapter.getLista().clear();
        adapter.getLista().addAll(listaDati);
        // fire the event
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Now when I retreive the value of characteristic I have thid code:

```
@Override
        public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt, BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
            //RECUPERO IL CORPO DEL MESSAGGIO
            try{
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(characteristic.getValue()).order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);

                byte[] value=buffer.array();

                int valore1 = new Integer(value[3]) * 256 + new Integer(value[2]);
                int valore2 = new Integer(value[5]) * 256 + new Integer(value[4]);
                int valore3 = new Integer(value[7]) * 256 + new Integer(value[6]);
                int valore4 = new Integer(value[9]) * 256 + new Integer(value[8]);
                int valore5 = new Integer(value[11]) * 256 + new Integer(value[10]);
                int valore6 = new Integer(value[13]) * 256 + new Integer(value[12]);
                int valore7 = new Integer(value[15]) * 256 + new Integer(value[14]);
                int valore8 = new Integer(value[17]) * 256 + new Integer(value[16]);

        SensorData mSenData = new SensorData(contatore,valore1+"",valore2+"",valore3+"",
                        valore4+"",valore5+"",valore6+"",valore7+"",valore8+"",
                        Constants.CHARACTERISTIC_FORZA_STRING,
                        db.getDateTime(true));
                mSenData.setValueTimestamp(db.getDateTime(true));

                refreshListView(mSenData);

                db.insertSensorData(mSenData);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

        }
```

In this method I have refreshListView method, I pass at it, the new SensorData object. This is the method:

```
public void refreshListView(SensorData newRelevation) {
        adapter.getLista().add(0,newRelevation);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

But if I try to start this code, I don't have any error but the listview not automatically refresh.

Consider that I receive a new value every 5 - 10 millisecond.

Comment: does your BLE device notify the characteristics has been changed?

Comment: throught Ble streaming

Comment: have you tried debugging? Does it fire `onCharacteristicChanged`?

Comment: Yes the data are correctly storage in my database

Comment: you probably should call `refreshListView` on UI thread. I'm not sure on which thread `onCharacteristicChanged` is called

Comment: Ok the problem is, I receive this date in onCharacteristicChanged method, and I have refresh my list view with this new Object. Now how can I do this ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173875/discussion-between-bircastri-and-vladyslav-matviienko).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `ScheduledExecutorService` as it is very accurate and offloads the UI to a thread. Here's an example :

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import static java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;

private final ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool( 1 );
```

Then call this function:

```
 private final int INTERVAL = 1000; // milli-seconds

private void scheduleAtFixedRate() {
    final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(r, 0, INTERVAL , MILLISECONDS);
}
```

In `onDestroy` call:

```
scheduler.shutdown();
```